# Chmod doesn't change permissions

Tags: bash

I have a file named replace.txt with 777 permissions. when running the command:

```
chmod 755 replace.txt
```

the permissions don't change accordingly. I checked with the

```
ls -l
```

command and it still shows the same permissions as before.
I've tried to run the command as:

```
sudo chmod 755 replace.txt
```

and it still won't work. Furthermore, I checked if the command was successful by using

echo $?

and it returns 0, meaning it was successul. Yet, no permissions were changed.
Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: It sounds like the filesystem might not support Unix permissions. What does `mount` show as the filesystem type? Is this a flash drive or a Windows filesystem or something? What variant of Unix?

Comment: This question is a better fit for [Super User](https://superuser.com) but isn't completely out of scope for Stack Overflow. So while I'm not voting to close, you may want to ask there (with more detail).

Comment: Can you write in the directory? Try `touch newfile.txt` of `ls -la .`.

Comment: I'm running it on Lubuntu 18.04, using its filesystem so I have no idea why it would not support Unix permissions. I can write in the directory but can't change the permissions.

Comment: Sounds like it's a symlink. Can you include the output of `ls -l`?